# The limit of a quotient of integral moments

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, uniform-integrability

I have the following quotient
$$
\frac{\int_k^\infty x^1 \ f(x) dx}{\int_k^\infty x^{1+\delta} \ f(x) dx}
$$
Where $f(x)$ is bounded and $\delta>0$.

I am trying to prove that as $k\to\infty$ the quotient becomes 0. If it were necessary, I can also assume that both integrals exist and are bounded, but it doesn't seem necessary. Also, $f(x)$ is a pdf, and it would be ok to show the statement for continuous functions.

It seems to be pretty intuitive but I cannot come up with an formal way of showing it. I am just not used to dealing with quotients of integrals.

Comment: Are there any more conditions on $f$? Do we know, for instance, that the integrals exist at all?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the existence of the integral. I assume you that it is no infinity or something similar, in that case yes. It should have some finite value, but I cannot find it.
Also, $f$ is a pdf for a random variable so its integral along the real line is 1.
Would they be necessary condition to say something about quotient?

Comment: For the quotient to be well defined, both integrals have to be well defined. For instance, there are some bounded functions $f$ with $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ simply undefined, so it wouldn't make sense to talk about $\frac{\int_0^1 f(x) dx}{\int_0^1 x f(x) dx}$ in this case.

Comment: I cannot think of an example, but it sounds possible. We can assume that the integrals are well defined in that case. Also, I exchanged numerator and denominator. Since the numerator can become zero (and should for my particular problem).

Comment: Examples include the indicator function for the rationals if you're using the Riemann integral and the indicator function for the Vitali set for the Lebesgue integral. :)

Comment: Ok wow, no this should be much simpler than those kind of examples. That's way over my head. I'd be just happy to show the statement for much simpler pdfs, even for continuous $f(x)$ would be enough. Maybe I wasn't specific enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a_k,b_k)=\left(\int_k^\infty xf(x)\,dx, \int_k^\infty x^{1+\delta}f(x)\,dx\right)$ both be finite.  The integrand in the $b_k$ integral is pointwise greater than $x k^\delta f(x)$, so $b_k\ge k^\delta a_k$, and so  $a_k/b_k\le k^{-\delta}$, which tends to $0$ as $k\to \infty,$ as desired.